# Flutter cannot drag pageview vertically

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter, so if my question is a dumb question, please don't throw me a stone :p :D

First, some of the following images might be familiar to you, I am only using this app from github, to test the teory. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgfMdhV4HQI&t=370s

**My Question:**

I am using pageview to navigate between two pages one with some dragable containers, and another page with some more dragable containers that represent a different topic.

If I define the **scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,** it work quit fine. But I want to drag it vertically.

[image]

If I define **scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,** I realised that, I only have a small portion of the screen where I am able to drag the page.

[image]

To my understanding, it might be related with the containers.

- **How can I drag vertically, while touching any where on the screen?**

Note: I also tested the SliverToBoxAdapter class without good results.

my git repro https://github.com/engineerRFR/flutter-mytest

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Netflix UI Redesign',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.pink,
              child: HomeScreen(),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: photoGallery(),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
          ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        onPageChanged: (num) {
          print("Page number : " + num.toString());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


 photoGallery (){
  return PageView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.amber,

      )
```

,

Comment: I created the same project and it works out-of-the-box with the code that you provided, I was able to drag and scroll from anywhere on the page. Maybe there is something more in the app that you pulled from Github which affects the touch/gesture?

Comment: Hi Dusk, I also downloaded from git and added the pageView and the photoGallery () to be displayed on the second screen.

Comment: Can you share the git project?

Comment: tonight I will create the git. :)

Comment: my git repro https://github.com/engineerRFR/flutter-mytest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to our comments and as I was suspecting, the root of this problem is not your `PageView`.

If you check your `home_screen.dart`, the `body` of your `Scaffold` (line 121) is a `ListView`. If you change it to `Column` everything starts to work as you want!

And that's because `ListView` consumes all of the vertical scrolls and the event won't reach the outer `PageView`.

Comment: Is it just this?! I have so much to learn! :D Thanks very much Dusk, it worked!

Comment: @Richardd No problem :) I'm glad that I could help!